# Efficiency of page loading with more ampscript blocks

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is there a difference in performance between this block of ampscript,

```
%%[ 
    if condition 
        set x = 1
    elseif another_condition
        set x = 0
    endif
]%%
```

and this one?

```
%%[ if condition
        set x = 1 ]%%
%%[ elseif another_condition
        set x = 0 ]%%
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Im curious to know how the server renders/scans the ampscript. Does it take a hit with each `%%[` or `]%%`? Or does it scan the logic all at once and there's no hit in efficiency or performance with each closing/opening ampscript tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Edited to better clarify my test code)*

I've tested this today on a microsite, using javascript to time the page load. The javascript is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
      var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 
      console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime);
      }
</script>
```

Page load times vary within reasonable expectations (+/- 50ms or so), but from my findings, averages based off ten refreshes of the following in Chrome are:

With nothing but the javascript to track load time: **228ms**

```
1.<script type="text/javascript">
2.    window.onload = function () {
3.      var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 
4.      console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime);
5.      }
6.</script>
```

With 1000 empty lines after: **528ms**

```
1.<script type="text/javascript">
2.    window.onload = function () {
3.      var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 
4.      console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime);
5.      }
6.</script>
7.
8.
9.
...
...
998.
999.
1000.
```

With 1000 lines of alternating opening/closing tags after: **1973ms**

```
1.<script type="text/javascript">
2.    window.onload = function () {
3.      var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 
4.      console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime);
5.      }
6.</script>
7.%%[
8.
9.]%%
10.%%[
11.
12.]%%
...
...
995.%%[
996.
997.]%%
998.%%[
999.
1000.]%%
```

With 1000 lines of opening/closing tags on each line (ouch): **47969ms**

```
1.<script type="text/javascript">
2.    window.onload = function () {
3.      var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart; 
4.      console.log('Page load time is '+ loadTime);
5.      }
6.</script>
7.%%[ ]%%
8.%%[ ]%%
9.%%[ ]%%
...
...
998.%%[ ]%%
999.%%[ ]%%
1000.%%[ ]%%
```

After much more than that, the page times out and fails to render.

Based on these findings, we can conclude that there is an exponential increase in page load time after a certain point, as should be expected from any serverside language. While the difference in your example would be negligible, this should be kept in mind for larger projects. Also consider that these tests are with empty opening/closing tags. Any logic performed within would quickly increase this overhead.

Feel free to test this on your own using similar parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's no appreciable performance in execution. Feel free to use whichever you feel more comfortable using.